# What does the 'weight' parameter mean in the Open CV object dectection

Tags: c++, opencv

In the open CV docs for the [`runAt` method](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#cascadeclassifier-runat), and also for the [detectMultiScale method](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#cascadeclassifier-detectmultiscale). There is a mysterious undocumented 'weight' output parameter.

From experimentating with my 2 stage classifier I have seen it spit out values like this:

```
-2.093535
-2.715030
2.000000   // Positive values seem to be output when the classifier was successful
0.034417
```

I have also looked thiough the souce code and found that the `groupRectangles` method uses the weights.

```
void groupRectangles(vector<Rect>& rectList, 
                     int groupThreshold, 
                     double eps, 
                     vector<int>* weights, 
                     vector<double>* levelWeights);
```

I guess its some kind of parameter which indicates how sure the classifier is that it has found the object, however, I do not know the details:

- What are the minimum and maximum values?
- What do positive and negative values mean?
- Is it linear or exponential?
- Is it related to the stages of the classifier?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out from the [cascadedetect source code](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/e59c74e1c7672ad16056f32136a491b1e008e295/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.hpp).  It uses the notation `sum` for the weight.

The code (below) iterates though the trees in a given stage adding to `sum` variable.  At the end of the stage the sum must be greater than the stage's threshold value (which can be negative) in order to proceed.  The sum is then reset to zero at the beginning of each new stage.

Therefore the weight output parameter is either:

- The value that failed to be larger than the threshold on the failed stage.
- OR .. The value that passed the final stage of the classifier.

I still don't understand what it means in absolute terms.

```
inline int predictOrderedStump( CascadeClassifier& cascade, Ptr<FeatureEvaluator> &_featureEvaluator, double& sum )
{
    int nodeOfs = 0, leafOfs = 0;
    FEval& featureEvaluator = (FEval&)*_featureEvaluator;
    float* cascadeLeaves = &cascade.data.leaves[0];
    CascadeClassifier::Data::DTreeNode* cascadeNodes = &cascade.data.nodes[0];
    CascadeClassifier::Data::Stage* cascadeStages = &cascade.data.stages[0];

    int nstages = (int)cascade.data.stages.size();
    for( int stageIdx = 0; stageIdx < nstages; stageIdx++ )
    {
        CascadeClassifier::Data::Stage& stage = cascadeStages[stageIdx];
        sum = 0.0;

        int ntrees = stage.ntrees;
        for( int i = 0; i < ntrees; i++, nodeOfs++, leafOfs+= 2 )
        {
            CascadeClassifier::Data::DTreeNode& node = cascadeNodes[nodeOfs];
            double value = featureEvaluator(node.featureIdx);
            sum += cascadeLeaves[ value < node.threshold ? leafOfs : leafOfs + 1 ];
        }

        if( sum < stage.threshold )
            return -stageIdx;
    }

    return 1;
}
```